# Kendo-UI Grid Get Cell value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been trying to get this piece of code to work for a while now, and I have run out of ideas. I looked online and could not find anything helpful.

I have a grid defined which has a lists of persons. User can click on the person to add it to their contacts. I have a custom command which does a post to my Action.

This is probably going to end up being something simple that I am overlooking..

I am unable to get the dataItem of the Grid. Following is the error I receive:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
y.extend.dataItem 
addContact
p.isFunction.f
p.event.dispatch 
g.handle.h
```

Following is my Javascript function:

```
function addContact(e) {

        debugger;

        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr")); // <-- ERRORS HERE
        var id = dataItem.Id

        var url = "@Url.Action("AddContact", "Contacts")";

        alert(url);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { contactID: id },
        });
    }
```

Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(ViewBag.Contacts as List<Contacts>)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ReleaseDate);
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Add").Click("addContact")).Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Add Contact" });
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Server()
    .PageSize(50))
)
```

Used scripts:

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your JS you need to grab a reference to your grid instead of using this.

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end, the issue was with the Grid configuration.

I had to set DataSource to Ajax binding instead of Server. Server binding prevents any client side data from being saved.

Comment: cheers, I was stumped for ages on the same issue, seems odd because I am binding to the model, not using ajax so why have to set ajax is beyond me.